# How can I implement INotifyPropertyChanged to make Xamarin binding update?I

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
        wordGrid.BindingContext = AS.phrase;
        AS.phrase = new PSCViewModel() { English = "abcd" };
        AS.phrase.English = "JJJJ";
```

With the setting of BindingContext on the first line I don't see anything in my view. With it after it works and I see "JJJJ".

Here is my viewModel:

```
public class PSCViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    int id;
    string english;

    public PSCViewModel()
    {
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != id)
            {
                id = value;
                onPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }

    public string English
    {
        get { return english; }
        set
        {
            if (value != english)
            {
                english = value;
                onPropertyChanged("English");
            }
        }
    }

    private void onPropertyChanged(string v)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone see why the change to the English field would not cause the new value of JJJJ to be displayed?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't bind before it's affected to `AS.Phrase` at this line `AS.phrase = new PSCViewModel() { English = "abcd" };`. The constructor  is done before the affection.

Comment: A workaround here is to use a method `CopyFrom(PSCViewMode psc)` which copy each properties (be sure it call the set) and call it when the object is already instanced. But usually you got your data after instantiation if it come from a database.

Comment: Would another work around be to rebind again with: wordGrid.BindingContext = AS.phrase;  each time a new object is assigned to AS.phrase? This doesn't happen often in the app. Just every 15 seconds.

Comment: Your problem occurred only because when you are doing the affectation of English (`{ English = "abcd" }`), the object is not yet linked to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
    public class Bindable : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Dictionary<string, object> _properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of a property
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            object value = null;
            if (_properties.TryGetValue(name, out value))
                return value == null ? default(T) : (T)value;
            return default(T);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value of a property
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        protected void Set<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            if (Equals(value, Get<T>(name)))
                return;
            _properties[name] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Here is a sample class describing how to use

```
    public class Transaction : Bindable
    {
        public Transaction()
        {
            this.TransactionDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            this.TransactionType = TransactionType.Add; //enum
            this.Quantity = 0;
            this.IsDeleted = false;
            this.Item = null; //object defined elsewhere
        }

        public Guid Id { get { return Get<Guid>(); } private set { Set<Guid>(value); } }
        public DateTimeOffset? TransactionDate { get { return Get<DateTimeOffset?>(); } set { Set<DateTimeOffset?>(value); } }
        public TransactionType TransactionType { get { return Get<TransactionType>(); } set { Set<TransactionType>(value); } }
        public double? Quantity { get { return Get<double?>(); } set { Set<double?>(value); } }
        public bool? IsDeleted { get { return Get<bool?>(); } set { Set<bool?>(value); } }
        public byte[] RowVersion { get { return Get<byte[]>(); } private set { Set<byte[]>(value); } }

        public virtual Guid? ItemId { get { return Get<Guid?>(); } set { Set<Guid?>(value); } }
        public virtual Item Item { get { return Get<Item>(); } set { Set<Item>(value); } }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably already found the [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) in `System.ComponentModel`

It's all part of MVVM. Your ViewModel must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There is only one event in it: `PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged`

I usually define a raise method in the ViewModel like this:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
   {
     PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

Then all the properties in the ViewModel must have they getter/setter like this:

```
public string AProperty
{
  get { return aProperty;}
  set 
  {
    if(value != aProperty)
    {
      aProperty = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("AProperty");
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when you bind your View with the ViewModel, it will subscribe to PropertyChanged event an propagate the changes. That's it !

Comment: I tried what you mentioned and then did a change. But I don't see any change in what's displayed. I will update the question.  Perhaps you can see what's wrong.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

A good start would be to read up on the MVVM pattern and how to implement it in Xamarin Forms. Xamarin has their own tutorials on the topic such as this one:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

Basically what you  do is create a ViewModel which acts as the `BindingContext` for the entire page. Within that ViewModel you define properties that are bound to your controls such as `Labels`, `ListViews` and `TextBoxes`. In your case the ViewModel would contain a `string` property called Phrase that is bound to the control called `wordGrid`.

```
public class PhraseViewModel
{
    public string Phrase {get; set;}
}
```

Which can be bound in XAML to e.g. a Label like:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Phrase}" />
```

Comment: I already have a view model looking like this:  public class PSCViewModel : IPhrase, IScore, ICategory
 {
  public PSCViewModel()
  {
  }


  public string English { get; set; }

Comment: but do I need to just implement INotifyPropertyChanged or is there more that needs to be done?

Comment: Did you read the link I posted and look at the code mentioned in it? To get binding (or more specifically updating of values) to work you will need NotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks Steven.  I did check out the docs but it still doesn't seem to work even after I made the code the same as in the docs.